# Count no. Of ways

Tags: permutations, binomial-coefficients, combinations

If $n$ identical balls put into $m$ identical boxes, how many ways it can be done, provided that boxes may be empty and all balls  have to be put into these boxes at each time.

Comment: You are looking for the number of *partitions* of $n$ into $m$ or fewer parts. No nice formula, big literature.

Comment: You might find reading about the 12 fold way helpful:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way

Answer (score 0):

If the boxes are distinguishable (box 1, box 2, ..., box m) then this is the same as the number of monomials in $m$ variables of degree $n$, and is equal to $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
m+n-1 &\\
n & \end{array} \right)$

Here is a really nice proof/explanation: http://murphmath.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/counting-monomials/

If the boxes are indistinguisable, then [Integer partition with fixed number of summands but without order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54635/integer-partition-with-fixed-number-of-summands-but-without-order) answers this.

Comment: Presumably the OP meant boxes that are indistinguishable from one another.  Your answer assumes the boxes are distinguishable (i.e. labelled).

Comment: Ok I didn't take identical to mean indistinguishable when reading the question, maybe I should have.  I'll add this case.

Comment: Basically it is, how many ways you can do partition of n in string of m length , zero can be included in the string