# Number of integer partitions of a natural number

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Consider $S \in \mathbb{N}$ where $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers. I want to obtain $S$ by summing $k$ natural numbers strictly positive. I want to find how many possibilities I have to obtain $S$ by summing $k$ numbers, considering that:

1) order does not matter, e.g. $2+1+3$ is the same as $3+1+2$

2) repetitions are allowed

Comment: This is called the number of _integer partitions_ of $S$.

Comment: Ok, I change the question title, thank you

Comment: @MartinR Nice work, couldn't find it but I was sure there was a dupe _somewhere_.

Comment: The number of addends is fixed in my case

Comment: @Cris Then there is another dupe, searching...

Comment: @Cris: You are right, that one is not exactly the same question. But I am sure that it has been answered before.

Comment: Found it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54635/integer-partition-with-fixed-number-of-summands-but-without-order/54649#54649

Comment: This is [OEIS A000041](https://oeis.org/A000041).